# Access Android Code of app created by PhoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a PhoneGap app, but the only part I'm interested in is the Android version. Is there any way to access the generated Android code in order to modify it?

Comment: What do you mean 'generated Android code'?

Comment: Are you building locally or with PhoneGap Build service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, my question was based on the wrong assumption that PhoneGap would generate some native code in order to build the app.

So what I wanted is close to the method described here: http://catchmayuri.blogspot.in/2011/05/getting-access-of-android-java-code-to.html